# Status bar gets grey background when locking screen to landscape

Tags: android, angular, cordova, capacitor

In my Angular app I use Capacitor and [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/) to rotate the orientation to landscape while playing a video with the Angular YouTube player. When the view is rotated the status bar moves to the top of the page as expected, but (now on the left of the device) where the status bar used to be the background color has changed to grey.

Enjoy this artists rendition:

[image]

I use the orientation mainly while playing a YouTube video, so my component checks if the video is playing and then locks the screen to landscape:

```js
if (this.playerIsPlaying) {
  window.screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
  StatusBar.hide();
} else {
  window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
  StatusBar.show();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using window.screen.orientation if your using the plugin. Just use 1. And you should also be using the event Listener to listen when the screen changes. The link you provided shows an example.

Comment: The plugin adds the following to the screen object (window.screen). What do you mean i shouldn't use window.screen? @StackoverBlows also I'm using this to force a landscape lock to show the video full screen.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone ever comes across this point, the answer is:

`<item name="android:background">#000000</item>`, I had the color value set to `@null`. Changing it to black fixed the difference in background color for me.

Comment: Also make sure you add this to the appropriate theme (values or values-night).

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add an  to `AppTheme.NoActionBar` in `styles.xml`, otherwise the status bar color would extend into the black vertical bar and look rather strange.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">default</item>
</style>
```